# R Markdown - knitting to bookdown::word_document2 fails because of officer::ftext used in inline code

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, officer

Minimum Reproducible example of my R notebook (.Rmd) file which causes the error while knitting to word document:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: bookdown::word_document2
---

Using inline R code chunks with `officer::ftext` causes an error as such


`r officer::ftext('Example text', officer::fp_text(color = 'red'))`
```

The error when knitting is as follows:

```
Error in vapply(x, format_sci_one, character(1L), ..., USE.NAMES = FALSE) : values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[2]]) results in length 8 Calls: <Anonymous> ... paste -> hook -> .inline.hook -> formact_sci -> vapply
```

This error started occurring only recently. Previously with this code, I was able to output a word document where the inline code chunk would produce text 'Example text' with red font color.

My .SessionInfo() output is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
[5] LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ROracle_1.3-1.1 DBI_1.1.2      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1  bookdown_0.24   fastmap_1.1.0   htmltools_0.5.2 tools_3.5.1     yaml_2.2.1      rmarkdown_2.11  knitr_1.37      xfun_0.29       digest_0.6.29  
[11] rlang_0.4.12    evaluate_0.14
```

I'm using Pandoc 2.1.
Please note that I'm using this R setup at work, so I'm not able to update to a newer version of R or RStudio IDE.

Comment: Can confirm the bug is also present in R 4.1.2 and Rstudio desktop (I'm also on Ubuntu, so not an issue of OS).

Comment: Updating sessionInfo() outtput after loading packages used in the working R Notebook. For some reason I cannot edit my question so I'm posting it in the comments

Comment: `other attached packages:
 [1] ftExtra_0.0.3     flextable_0.5.10  officer_0.3.11    bookdown_0.24     knitr_1.37        rmarkdown_2.11    mgsub_1.7.3       lubridate_1.8.0   readxl_1.3.1     
[10] data.table_1.14.2 scales_1.1.1      ggplot2_3.3.5     tidyr_1.1.4       dplyr_1.0.7       ROracle_1.3-1.1   DBI_1.1.2 `

Comment: `loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_2.0.3         Rcpp_1.0.7        pillar_1.6.4      compiler_3.5.1    cellranger_1.1.0  base64enc_0.1-3   tools_3.5.1       uuid_1.0-3        digest_0.6.29    
[10] evaluate_0.14     lifecycle_1.0.1   tibble_3.1.6      gtable_0.3.0      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.12      yaml_2.2.1        xfun_0.29         fastmap_1.1.0    
[19] xml2_1.3.3        withr_2.4.3       systemfonts_1.0.3 gdtools_0.2.3     generics_0.1.1    vctrs_0.3.8       grid_3.5.1        tidyselect_1.1.1  glue_1.6.0 ...`

Comment: `... [28] R6_2.5.1          fansi_0.5.0       purrr_0.3.4       magrittr_2.0.1    ellipsis_0.3.2    htmltools_0.5.2   colorspace_2.0-2  utf8_1.2.2        munsell_0.5.0    
[37] crayon_1.4.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Rmd file started knitting properly to word after I installed and loaded package `officedown` version 0.1.0. I initially tried with version 0.2.0, but then if I used non-alphanumeric characters as text input in `officer::ftext` function (eg. '%', '[') in the word output it appeared as an xml structure instead of formatted text.

Credit goes to David Gohel, developer of the `officer` packages who pointed me to the `officedown` package, see discussion on his github page:
https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/issues/402